# How to add Prompt in retriver in Retrievalqa in langchain

Tags: langchain, py-langchain, weaviate

i am trying to use retrievalqa from langchain to implement a chatmodel.while using the retrievalQA i get know that there is no option to add the retrival. how to add the retrieval in retrivalqa

vectordb=Weaviate(client,'Document', 'page_content')
qa_chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(OpenAI(temperature=0),chain_type_kwargs={"prompt":PROMPT},chain_type="stuff", )
no option to add retriever

Comment: [PrivateDocBot](https://github.com/Abhi5h3k/PrivateDocBot)

Created using langchain and chainlit 

It also streams using langchain just like ChatGpt it displays word by word and works locally on PDF data. ‍ 

code reference.